# How to identify columns by pattern and convert it to datetime using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

I have a data frame called `data` like as shown below

```
 structure(list(NRIC_ID = c(1234L, 4567L, 1234L, 3578L, 2468L), 
    ADMIT_DATE = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("11/11/2011", 
    "2/12/2016", "3/11/2019", "5/7/2018", "7/7/2014"), class = "factor"), 
    test_date = structure(c(3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c(" 2014-17-11", 
    "10/8/2013", "11/2/2012", "12/12/2012", "12/2/2014"), class = "factor"), 
    test2_DATE = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("11/11/2011", 
    "2/12/2016", "3/11/2019", "5/7/2018", "7/7/2014"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Currently when I get the datatypes of the columns using the below code

```
(sapply(data, class))
```

I get the output as `Integer`, `Date`, and `character`.

Now, I would like to identify all the columns that contain `DATE` or `date` in their column name using pattern matching and convert them to the `Date` data type

I tried the below code for pattern matching

```
data %>%
  select(contains("date")) %>%  #how to ignore case here
  as.Date()
```

When I do this, I get the below error

> Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert '.' to class "Date"

can help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mutate` if you want to operate on the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains('date', ignore.case = TRUE), 
          lubridate::parse_date_time, c('dmY', 'mdY', 'Ydm')))

#  NRIC_ID ADMIT_DATE  test_date test2_DATE
#1    1234 2016-12-02 2012-02-11 2016-12-02
#2    4567 2019-11-03 2014-02-12 2019-11-03
#3    1234 2018-07-05 2013-08-10 2018-07-05
#4    3578 2014-07-07 2014-11-17 2014-07-07
#5    2468 2011-11-11 2012-12-12 2011-11-11
```

Comment: Thanks.Upvoted. Will try..I updated the same data above.. Does this work still?

Comment: I get an error as below `Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "packageIQR"`

Comment: This works only if your data follows the format `dmy`, if you have mixed date format use `parse_date_time`. `df %>% mutate(across(contains('date'), lubridate::parse_date_time, c('dmY', 'mdY')))`

Comment: @TheGreat Provide your data using `dput`. i.e `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Sure, preparing the input data..May I also know how to ignore the case `date` and `DATE` when we use `contains`?

Comment: I pasted `dput` command output and I get an error like as shown below `Error: Problem with mutate() input ..1.
x unused argument (ignore_case = TRUE)
i Input `..1` is `across(...).`

Comment: The problem is in my input file, it is only as factors...What if the file that comes in real time has a mix of `factors`, `date`, `character` data types for date columns?

Comment: The updated answer works for the data that you have shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226347/discussion-between-the-great-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table` and solution @Ronak Shah

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
cols_date <- grep(pattern = "date", x = names(dt), ignore.case = T, value = T)
dt[, lapply(.SD, parse_date_time, c('dmY', 'mdY', 'Ydm')), .SDcols = cols_date]

#>    ADMIT_DATE  test_date test2_DATE
#> 1: 2016-02-12 2012-02-11 2016-12-02
#> 2: 2019-03-11 2014-02-12 2019-11-03
#> 3: 2018-05-07 2013-08-10 2018-07-05
#> 4: 2014-07-07 2014-11-17 2014-07-07
#> 5: 2011-11-11 2012-12-12 2011-11-11
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted, May I know what does `value = T` and `.SD` and `.SDcols` mean?

Comment: `.SDcols` are used to specify which columns should be subset of the table `(.SD).`
`value =T` returns column names, `value = F` returns column numbers

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
addFormats("%Y-%d-%m")
df %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('DATE'), anydate))
```

-output

```
#   NRIC_ID ADMIT_DATE  test_date test2_DATE
#1    1234 2016-02-12 2012-11-02 2016-02-12
#2    4567 2019-03-11 2014-12-02 2019-03-11
#3    1234 2018-05-07 2013-10-08 2018-05-07
#4    3578 2014-07-07 2014-11-17 2014-07-07
#5    2468 2011-11-11 2012-12-12 2011-11-11
```

Comment: Thanks. upvoted. Does `anytime` help convert input date columns in whichever format to  the format mentioned in `addFormats` section? Is that what `anydate` does?

Comment: @TheGreat There are certain formats already built-in.  You can find them with `getFormats()` if any formats are not in those defaults, then add those formats with `addFormats`.  Having said that there are some cases which are very difficult to parse i.e. 2 digits year, along with 2 digit month, 2 digit day less than 12 etc which can be parsed in different ways

Comment: but `addFormats` is for specifying the output format of our date column. Am I right? Like shown in our code

Comment: @TheGreat It is for adding custom formats if any default formats to parse is missing.  The output format is always the `Date` class format which is `YYYY-MM-DD`